# Making a fancy looking window with messages stack

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I try to make fancy looking messages viewer, where messages divided by formatting, other background of smth. similar. They need to looks like this - http://pastebin.com/GU1Lq087. What I found in wxWidgets to solve this problem, and why I can't use it:

1. wxHtmlWindow

   Supports minimal HTML (a few tags). But big problem with this - html representation doesnt fill parent window. So element with width=100% will have 100% width only on standard window size. And even **p** tag doesnt have word wrapping (long long paragraph goes in one line with vertical scroolbar).
2. wxWebWiew

   I need to have the ability to set generated HTML to it, but IE must to load some page first and I can rely only on IE background. It has some time to load page, even if I set HTML-string.
3. wxRichText

   Most suitable for me. But I can't draw line like HTML's **hr**, or change background for the entire message block (to distinguish it from common background)

I need to show messages like [this](http://s003.radikal.ru/i203/1303/1a/598e08750166.jpg). But i didn't know how and which tool is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. One way of achieving this would be using wxWebView with WebKit backend but I am afraid that Windows can only use IE's engine. However, there is project which allows you to use Gecko engine. I use WebKit for rendering chat in my application and it works really good (although I am using Qt). (http://www.kirix.com/labs/wxwebconnect.html)
2. You can always do it regular way - just create separate widget (I think it is called "frame" in wxWidgets) for single message. This way you get almost infinite possibilities. E.g. you can make "AbstractMessage" with virtual methods and then things like "AdministratorMessage", "MOTD" etc. will be a breeze.

Comment: Awesome answer. I think, gecko will be overhead for this simple thing.

Comment: One instance of Gecko engine per application shouldn't be a problem  nowadays (budget laptops have 4GB+ ram and atleast 2 cores). Of course pure "wxWidgets" way would be most efficient because native drawing will always be best. Just try to minimize drawing effects "by hand". Try to use as many ready wx components as you can.
Keep in mind that I am writing it from the perspective of Qt user, but principle should be the same.
If you only knew what workarounds I had to do in my application e.g. to overcome licensing problems...

Answer (score 1):

*wxRichText Most suitable for me. But I can't draw line like HTML's hr*

Really?  Have you looked at the docs?

( http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_richtextctrl.html )

Here's a couple simple ideas:

a.  Write a line of blanks, underlined.

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_rich_text_ctrl.html#a333b2e675617ed2299cf91e7c0dbd0d8

b.  Create an image of a horizontal line, display it using WriteImage

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_rich_text_ctrl.html#a1315611c0741d03e852ee26eba3a9d94

Comment: ofc I have read docs, and think about 2 ways, but they are temporary fixes

Answer (score 1):

The funny thing is that what you want can be done using *any* of the 3 controls you mention. With `wxHtmlWindow` you just need to set its size correctly, with `wxWebView` I don't understand what your problem with it is at all and with `wxRichTextCtrl` you could just use separate controls for the areas with different backgrounds (you could almost certainly use a single control with different styles but using several controls seems simpler).

Comment: QT has VScrollContainer (or smth. like that) to hold controls and add vertical scrollbar if it needed, I will search something similar in wx, thanks

Comment: It's just `wxScrolledWindow`.

Comment: I can't get what must contains what. Now i have wxFrame contains sizer, that contains wxScrolledWindow that contains sizer, that contains all rich text controls. So i have scrollbar for each control

Comment: You need to size the inner text controls appropriately so that they fit their contents.

Comment: But is there *min-height* or auto height? Because messages can be long and can be short. Fixed height not working for that